# django channel websocket failed

Tags: django, docker, vue.js, websocket, django-channels

in my frontend which is built with vue js , alongside npm run serve ( running outside docker) the webscocket throw this error
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws/notifications/' failed:

My infrsactructure in docker , is looking like this

**Backend**
Code of Backend\Backend\asgi.py

```
"""
ASGI config for Backend project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

# Setting the default Django settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Backend.settings')

# Import the WebSocket routing from your notifications app (not the Backend app)
import notifications.routing

# Create the ProtocolTypeRouter and include both the standard Django application
# and the websocket application from the routing you've created in your notifications app.
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(notifications.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
    ),
})
```

Code of Backend\Backend\wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for Backend project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Backend.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Code of Backend\Backend\settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for Backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-%i4o(&moci^cv2dv_uiax#hp-!gwevch0$t7&16&a7^9l8gsaz'


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'djoser',
    'debimetre',
    'prediction',
    'notifications',
     'channels',
     'daphne',


]

# Use channels for default backend
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'Backend.asgi.application'



# Configuration for channels with Redis as message broker
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('redis', 6379)],
        },
    },
}


CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://redis:6379/1',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
        }
    }
}
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'Backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'your_log_file.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Code of Backend\Backend\routing.py

```
# Backend/routing.py

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from notifications import consumers  # Import the consumer from the notifications app

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/notifications/<str:room_name>/', consumers.NotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),

]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns),
})
```

Code of Backend\notifications\consumers.py

```
# notifications/consumers.py

import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class NotificationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

Code of Backend\notifications\routing.py

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from notifications import consumers



websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/notifications/', consumers.NotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),
]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns),
})
```

Code of Backend\Dockerfile

```
# Use a slim version to reduce image size
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Copy just the requirements file and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application
COPY . .

# Copy the startup script
COPY start.sh /app/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/start.sh

# Use the startup script as the entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/start.sh"]
CMD ["daphne", "-p", "8000", "Backend.asgi:application"]
```

Code of Backend\start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start Daphne for WebSockets
daphne Backend.asgi:application -p 8001 &


# Start Gunicorn for HTTP requests
exec gunicorn Backend.wsgi:application -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Code of Backend\docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build: Backend/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./Backend:/app

  frontend:
    build: frontend/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app

  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

frontend

code that is reponsible to connect to webscocket

```
function initWebSocket() {
  const url = "ws://localhost:8000/ws/notifications/";
  socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(url);

  socket.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
    console.log("WebSocket connected!", event);
  });

  socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    notification.value = data.message;
  });

  socket.addEventListener("close", (event) => {
    console.log("WebSocket closed!", event);
  });
}
```

I did try to use nginx in django
and change the code settings with no solution

Answer (score 0):

your backend and frontend are in two different containers . so web socket url you have mentioned will connect to frontend container's 8000 .`"ws://localhost:8000/ws/notifications/"` . try changing the url to `ws://${BACKEND_IP}:${BACKEND_PORT}/ws/notifications/` . This should solve the problem . Also remember that services in same `docker-compose` file will be in same default network . But You can't use backend as domain name because , there is error in resolving to IP . check this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77397698/20175872) .